# Leave associated type unspecified in trait implementation

Tags: rust

I want to leave an associated type specification in a trait implementation for later, as it requires some work. Is there any way I can tell the compiler to ignore the missing associated type?

```
impl A for B {
    type C = todo()!;
}
```

It throws this error

```
error: non-type macro in type position: ::core::panic
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust macros like `todo!()` aren't magic, they must expand to valid Rust code. In the case of `todo()` it expands to `panic!("not yet implemented: ....")` (see [src](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/macros/mod.rs.html#639-642)).

If you use a macro in a *type*, then it must expand to a valid *type*. Unfortunately, that means you can't have it expand to the equivalent of `todo!()`: it wouldn't really make sense!

However, instead, you can use `()` as a placeholder, or even define a custom type alias: `type Todo = ()`.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't leave `()` as a placeholder, as there are other constraints that affect that type

Comment: Unfortunately, because of Rust's static typing you can't really 'partially' type a program, so you'll have to provide _a_ valid type for this constraint even if it isn't your final choice.

Comment: Your best shot then is - if you are on nightly - to use the `never` type such as `type C = !;`. `never` implements some traits from stdlib and everything coerces to it, so you won't get the compiler complaining as much - until it complains constantly because all you do is generate dead code

Comment: An empty enum type might be a good replacement for `!` on stable- something like `enum Todo{}`. If any trait bounds are needed implement them by unconditionally panicking on all methods.